# What is the density function of $V=U^{-a}$, where $a>0$ and $U$ is a uniform random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

I'm working through some of the questions in the textbook, "Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis" by John Rice and am having some difficulties with this question.

I start off with $F_V(v)=P(V\leq v)=P(U^{-a}\leq v)=P(U\geq v^{-1/a})=1-P(U<v^{-1/a})=F_U(v^{-1/a})$

Assuming what I did above is correct, should I be taking the derivative of $F_U(v^{-1/a})$ to find $f_v(v)$?

Am I done after taking the derivative or do I need to find the domain of the variable? How would you find the domain?

Comment: Only real caveat is that this may not make sense if $U$ takes negative values.

Comment: Would finding the domain of $v$ prevent that?

Comment: No, it is just a problem of computing say $(-1)^{-a}$. Even when this is fine (like when $a=1$), the non-monotonicity will change the derivation.

Comment: I reworded some of the original question to better fit the title, maybe I interpreted the question wrong?: https://imgur.com/BICVlZS

Comment: I think this question has it so that $U$ is only on the interval $[0,1]$, I hope that changes things.

Comment: The wording of that makes it *sound* like $U$ is on $(0,1)$, since it's talking about the tail which only even exists when $U$ can be arbitrarily small. But it's not explicit.

Comment: How would you do this question assuming $U$ is only on $(0,1)$?

Comment: $P(U^{-a} \leq v)=P(U \geq v^{-1/a})=1-v^{-1/a}$ whenever $v \in (0,\infty)$. Then take the derivative.

Comment: @Ian I think the support of $V$ is $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. (Really, $v^{-1/a}$ should be in $(0,1)$ and you can figure out what that means for $v$ itself from there on the fly.)